# how can I find related keywords with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to elasticsearch and already love it.

Right know I am interested in understanding on how I can let elasticsearch make suggestions for similar keywords.

I have already read this article: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html.

> The More Like This Query (MLT Query) finds documents that are "like" a given set of documents.

This is already more than I am looking for. I dont need similar documents but only related / similar keywords.

So lets say I have an index of documents about movies and I start a query about "godfather". Then elasticsearch should suggest related keywords - e.g. "al pacino" or "Marlon Brando" because they are likely to occur in the same documents.

any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do that in **Elastic**. What you could possibly do, is to write a program, that will query **Elastic**, return matched documents, then you will get the `_source` data, or just retrieve it from your original datasource (like DB or file), later you will need to calculate [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) for each term in the retrieved ones and somehow combine everything all together to get **top K** terms out of all returned terms.

Comment: cool thanks for your ideas. I had assumed there is already function for that but now we will somehow work around. What do you think about using the inverted index? Lets say I have two keywords which occur in the same set of documents - then it seems reasonable to assume that they are closely related. But I fear that this will require a lot of ressources. When I have 1M keywords and I want to find out how closely they are related this will need a lot of machine power I guess.